# SteamBot - Send a Message with Trade

Tags: c#, steambot

I try to send a message when a user make a trade, but I can't find the way. I put SendMessage in TradeOfferUserHandle.cs:

```
public override void OnTradeInit() 
{ 

      SendChatMessage("Hi User, Trade start!"); 
}
```

But don't work. Any solution? I use C# SteamBot: https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem is that I need overwrite SimpleUserHandle.cs, not TradeOfferUserHandle.cs

Answer (score 0):

Because OnTradeInit is an override void, **it might not know what SendChatMessage is**.

You should **create a new void** called TradeMessage, and move SendChatMessage into that. Then, you need to call the TradeMessage void, from the OnTradeInit void.

And now, it **should** work.

Comment: I make this and don't work: `public override void OnTradeInit() {
            TradeMessage();
        }` in Trade Message I put SendChatMessage